# Simple way to flatten this array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have this array:

```
[{name: 'email',value: 'a@b.com'}, {name: 'phone',value: '123-123-1234'}]
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
{email: 'a@b.com', phone: '123-123-1234'}
```

How can I do this? I figure I can do a million iterators to get the job done, but I think maybe there's a cleaner way to do this.

I'm using Underscore and jQuery if that helps.

Comment: You'll have to interate one way or another, since you're turning an array into an object. `$.map` can convert objects into arrays, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that task.

One is using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr = [{name: 'email',value: 'a@b.com'}, {name: 'phone',value: '123-123-1234'}];
var obj = {};
arr.map(function (item) {
   var key = item.name;
   var value = item.value;
   if (!obj[key]) {
      obj[key] = value;
   }
});
console.log(obj);
```

As noted in the comments and other answer, [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a simple for-loop can get the job done as well.

Comment: This is not the only way, you can use  `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: reduce is better than map and the use of map in this answer makes no sense. It is being treated as an each loop. (And yes I know this is a 2+ year old question/answer)

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is pretty neat for this type of manipulation:

```
var items = [{name: 'email',value: 'a@b.com'}, {name: 'phone',value: '123-123-1234'}]

var data = items.reduce(function (result, item) {
    result[item.name] = item.value;

    return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: I think that this it's the most elegant and simple way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

UnderscoreJS is just awesome, and you may use `_.map`. See the code below:

```
var existingObject = [{name: 'email',value: 'a@b.com'}, {name: 'phone',value: '123-123-1234'}];
var selectedObject = _.map(existingObject, function(obj) {
    var retObj = { };
    retObj[obj["name"]] = obj["value"];
    return retObj;
});

console.log(selectedObject);
```